# WeakMap key not collected

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, weak-references

```
const frame = {
    key: {}
};

const map = new WeakMap();
map.set(frame.key, 'value');
console.log(map); // { {} -> 'value' }

delete frame.key;
// Force GC
console.log(map); // { {} -> 'value' }
```

In a snippet like this, why is the `key` not collected? I thought once I `delete` `key`, `frame` will stop holding onto it and its reference count will go to zero, thus either triggering GC or at least be collected by GC I trigger manually.

I have forced GC in Firefox by going to `about:memory` and clicking all the buttons in the *Free memory* box.

I assumed the map would either be empty or at least when inspecting it in the Developer Tools won't show the key as a live reference. But that's not what appears to be happening.

I can confirm the view in the Developer Tools is not outdated because I can drill down the map object through `entries[0]` and right-click on the `key`'s value selecting *Store as global object* and when I evaluate *that*, I get normal inspection, no errors, nothing.

Comment: GC is a fairly expensive task and does not run all the time. The JS engine decides when there is time available or the necessity to run another GC cycle.

Comment: I have manually forced the GC in FF and the key still hasn't gotten collected.